# What if humans had half the IQ they had today?

Tags: intelligence

What if, for some reason everyone on Earth's intelligence was half what it is now? How would this affect people’s day to day life? Like how would it change education, the economy, and politics etc.

Comment: Questions asking "What would be the effect of X on society?" are often closed as too broad.

Comment: I are the edits better

Comment: Instead of asking "How would this affect people's day to day life?" You're now asking that and "How would it change education, the economy, politics, etc..." Your question was too broad and your edits are expanding it's scope not restricting it.

Comment: Basically the IQ is computed so that the average person *of a given population* has an IQ of 100. You cannot compare IQ numbers across time, and comparing them across populations if iffy. See [Flynn effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn_effect).

Comment: @sphennings I direct you to the answer of James McLellan. This is the historic definition of IQ: ask any psychologist! Or here: http://www.ncme.org/ncme/NCME/Resource_Center/Glossary/NCME/Resource_Center/Glossary1.aspx?hkey=4bb87415-44dc-4088-9ed9-e8515326a061#anchorI

Comment: Back to the question, what does a correct answer look like? A correct answer could address one of a million things; and there could be a million answers, all equally correct. That makes this question too broad. I am voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

IQ was once measured as intellectual age compared to actual age. Although the measurement is deprecated, it's a very helpful way to visualize questions about intelligence. Using that measurement and your proposed cut in half, your new typical high school graduate would be as developed as a first grader for old humanity. Your forty year old peak earner, at the top of his professional mastery in new humanity would be as developed as an undergrad in old humanity.

There are recent studies that some animals, dogs in particular, are as smart as old human children. I'm not sure what it might be like if we weren't the most intelligent creatures on the planet.